# Runtime error for the storage Api for Windows 8 WinRT

Tags: cordova

I am making a framework for phonegap for windows 8 WinRT . I am working on the storage API. For that i have downloaded a sqlite with c++ project online and i am using that in my project by adding that reference in my WinRT project. But when i run the code and try and create a database i am getting an runtime error that "sqlite3.dll is not defined" . Is it that storage API is not supported for phonegap WinRT or there is a workaround for the same?.

I am able to create the database successfully for the phonegap WinJs project.